# Pretrained Fasttext model returns gibberish for out-of-vocabulary words

Tags: python, gensim, fasttext

I am experiencing a problem when using a pre-trained fasttext.bin model (retreived from  https://fasttext.cc/docs/en/crawl-vectors.html). Checking most_similar for in-vocabulary-words returns sensible responses. However, when checking most_similar for an out-of-vocabulary word that only differs one character returns gibberish.

My question: Has this something to do with the model, or am I using it in the wrong way?

```py
from gensim.models.wrappers import FastText
model = FastText.load_fasttext_format('cc.en.300.bin')
model.most_similar("universitet")
[('Universitet', 0.8522759675979614),
 ('högskolan', 0.677900493144989),
 ('Högskola', 0.6725144386291504),
 ('högskola', 0.6724666357040405),
 ('Högskolan', 0.6600401997566223),
 ('Universitetet', 0.6519213318824768),
 ('Høgskolen', 0.647462010383606),
 ('Universiteti', 0.6399329900741577),
 ('forskning', 0.617483377456665),
 ('språk', 0.6172543168067932)]

model.most_similar("universitett")
[('ESTATERETAILCONSUMERPHONESCARSBIKESAPPSINTERNETTABLETSCOMPUTERSSOCIETYPOLITICSLAWCRIMEENVIRONMENTSCIENCEARTSCELEBRITIESSPORTSSPECIALSFIRST',
  0.47905537486076355),
 ('Wikipedia-Page-Suzannah-B-Troy-6-yrs-after-Misogynist-Cyber-Vandalism-Censorship-via-Deletion-on-a-page-about-Censorship-Wikipedia-Agrees-to-retur',
  0.47733378410339355),
 ('DEky4M0BSpUOTPnSpkuL5I0GTSnRI4jMepcaFAoxIoFnX5kmJQk1aYvr2odGBAAIfkECQoABAAsCQAAABAAEgAACGcAARAYSLCgQQEABBokkFAhAQEQHQ4EMKCiQogRCVKsOOAiRocbLQ7EmJEhR4cfEWoUOTFhRIUNE44kGZOjSIQfG9rsyDCnzp0AaMYMyfNjS6JFZWpEKlDiUqALJ0KNatKmU4NDBwYEACH5BAkKAAQALAkAAAAQABIAAAhpAAEQGEiQIICDBAUgLEgAwICHAgkImBhxoMOHAyJOpGgQY8aBGxV2hJgwZMWLFTcCUIjwoEuLBym69PgxJMuDNAUqVDkz50qZLi',
  0.474983274936676),
 ('DEky4M0BSpUOTPnSpkuL5I0GTSnRI4jMepcaFAoxIoFnX5kmJQk1aYvr2odGBAAIfkECQoABAAsCQAAABAAEgAACGcAARAYSLCgQQEABBokkFAhAQEQHQ4EMKCiQogRCVKsOOAiRocbLQ7EmJEhR4cfEWoUOTFhRIUNE44kGZOjSIQfG9rsyDCnzp0AaMYMyfNjS6JFZWpEKlDiUqALJ0KNatKmU4NDBwYEACH5BAUKAAQALAkAAAAQABIAAAhpAAEQGEiQIICDBAUgLEgAwICHAgkImBhxoMOHAyJOpGgQY8aBGxV2hJgwZMWLFTcCUIjwoEuLBym69PgxJMuDNAUqVDkz50qZLi',
  0.47364047169685364),
 ('crescendosexibloguerobateyabsorbersexiindesignabledinerolatifundiosexibrezarcularsutesexirapoplinbrezarcorrentosoVd.lazadareflejoreglafeministabrezarchuzasexiouttiqueblogueroin',
  0.47090965509414673),
 ('QQFZAAEACwAAAAAGQASAAAIjgAJCBQIoGDBgQgTKiwooGHDgwshDgTgsOLDhAAGaAQwUYBBhx85EtS4cWLGjR5JSjxZkgDFkwwLohTJUqTLlANiwvQ4seVNjwwfBoVokKjFo0Jlksz506NFiklZtoQKFSjIoktLVv1YsahSn1WP0vzq02VYoAjJMsVYVKHZrDbdupW6Vq5cunHtRjQoMCAAIfkECRQABAAsCQADAAQABAAACAsABQgkILCgwYEBAQAh',
  0.46747487783432007),
 ('записиТелепрограммаVikerraadioOtseEsilehtJärelkuulamineSaatekavaPodcastidRaadioteaterRaadio',
  0.4659830331802368),
 ('deblogueroreflejoantecedentesexitlacuachebateysuteindesignableabsorbersexilatifundiosexibrezarsutemultiétnicosexiplinrapobrezarcorrentosoVd.lazadafisiochillidomabrezarsico-chuzaoutcolodrablogueroin',
  0.46159273386001587),
 ('2OtseEsilehtJärelkuulamineSaatedPodcastidKlassikaraadioOtseEsilehtJärelkuulamineSaatekavaPodcastidRaadio',
  0.4609595537185669),
 ('leilighetEiendomstypeSelveierleilighetPlass', 0.4550461769104004)]
```

Comment: If you try a word that is a shorter version of 'universitet' what are the results? E.g., 'universit'?

Comment: "universit" is an in-vocabulary-word and returns a normal response. If I try a shorter version of the in-vocabulary-word "pharmaceutical" , e.g. model.most_similar("pharmaceutica"), I still get gibberish

Comment: Have you tried the ".vec" file instead of ".bin"?

Comment: @JoshVoigts No, but if I am not mistaken the .vec only includes the word vectors and not the N-grams that are necessary for the construction of vectors for out-of-vocabulary-words

Comment: It could also be that the gensim library doesn't support out-of-vocab words, you could try using the fasttext [python](https://github.com/facebookresearch/fastText/tree/master/python) library instead?

Answer (score 0):

If I remember correctly "gensim.models.wrappers" is deprecated, try using

> from gensim.models.fasttext import FastText

Source : https://radimrehurek.com/gensim/models/wrappers/fasttext.html

Comment: Implementing this change does not resolve the issue and returns exactly the same gibberish

Comment: I've tried with the cc.en.300 model and go the same output as yours. However with another model (wiki.simple) I got decent words. It might be something related to the model. From my point of view, you're using the right method.

Comment: I agree. A second ago I did the same, and came to the same conclusion. Still wondering though what is going wrong with cc.en.300.bin. I don't expect it to be a mistake in the training, since it is retrieved from the official fasttext website

Comment: Just adding another confirmation that your model seems correct.